# How to initialize structure to zero everytime in while loop?

Tags: c++, structure

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
#define max 200005
struct st{
    ll index,freq,val;
}s[max];;

int main(){
    ll t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        ll n;
        cin>>n;
        ll counter[max]={0};
        for(ll i=1;i<=n;i++){
            ll x;
            cin>>x;
            s[x].val=x;
            s[x].index=i;
            s[x].freq++;
            cout<<s[x].freq<<endl;
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, how I will initialize struct to zero in every while loop. I have tried memset() but It is showing error. Also I created struct object in main function. But the program crashes. Please give me hints to solve the problem.

Comment: the first 4 lines of your code made me dizzy. Why are you writing code like that?

Comment: I am a beginner

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) / [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). `typedef long long ll;` is just "wtf?!?", just don't do it. And macros are not to define constants

Comment: ^^ No worries, thats why I try to tell you whats wrong about it ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 okay sir

Comment: Please show your failed `memset` attempt

Comment: @Surt I used `memset( &st, 0, sizeof(st) );`  in first line after while loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead, its more structured, usually less error prone.

```
std::fill(std::begin(s), std::end(s), st({0,0,0}));
```

I might even be converted to `memset` by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Surely there will be a better solution than this but you can add this snippet at the beginning of the while loop:

```
for(int j=0; j<max; j++){
    s[j].val=0;
    s[j].index=0;
    s[j].freq=0;
}
```

You can also consider the idea of redeclaring the struct array every time in the loop, just like this:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
#define max 200005
struct st{
    ll index,freq,val;
};

int main(){
    ll t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        st s[max];
        ll n;
        cin>>n;
        ll counter[max]={0};
        for(ll i=1;i<=n;i++){
            ll x;
            cin>>x;
            s[x].val=x;
            s[x].index=i;
            s[x].freq++;
            cout<<s[x].freq<<endl;
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will explode in your face if max stack is less than 200005*sizeof(long long)*3

Comment: I tried this method but it is showing tle

Comment: @the_noobie_coder What is tle? Not everyone follows competitive programming.

Comment: C++ developers usually get accustomed to using std::cin and std::cout for standard I/O operations, but they aren’t the fastest ones out there. If you are feeling lazy to change your code, you can…

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
#define max 200005
struct st{
    ll index,freq,val;
};

int main(){
    ll t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        st s[max]={0};
        ll n;
        cin>>n;
        ll counter[max]={0};
        for(ll i=1;i<=n;i++){
            ll x;
            cin>>x;
            s[x].val=x;
            s[x].index=i;
            s[x].freq++;
            cout<<s[x].freq<<endl;
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I did this.
The problem is solved. I used dev c++ ide, that's why the code was doing problem. Thanks all